# Yii2 - Get filtered values

Tags: php, gridview, yii, filter, yii2

I know this could be an unusual request but I hope someone can help me.

In my gridview, I need to get the filter's values, for example, if I select a specific date to display at my gridview as filter, I want to get the date selected, my goal is to be able to make a query with all filters. I do not know if there is a way to do it.

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: thjis should be the normal grdivew behavior .. update your question and show your grdiview  code

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself, the gridview works, show me all results that should be, my problem is: in my example, if I filter by date, let's say "2017-10-07", the gridview displays results of that date, but what I need is to get that date, not the rows, I would like to work with "2017-10-07"

Comment: `echo "<pre>";print_r($this->atrribute_name_of_date);die();` use this in search() method befor returning dataprovider this will print selected date search filter

Comment: try this Yii::$app->request->queryParams['SearchModelName'];

Comment: @ParitoshMahale I couldn´t try it but thanks

Comment: @VishvaG that's it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the filter values in your controller. In the example below use your filter field name index in the place of `myFilterName`.

```
public function actionIndex($indexDeleted=false)
{
    $queryparams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    $myDateValue = isset($queryparams['myFilterName']) ? $queryparams['myFilterName'] : null;

    $searchModel = new RecipeSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    ...
```